# Call a web-app script within a script with UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script deployed as a webapp. It is asking too many permissions to the user, so I want to divide the script in two parts. One will be run as the user so that I can get his/her email, the other one will be run as me to edit a spreadsheet.

I have tried to use the UrlFetchApp.fetch. I do not get an error, but the second script does not write in a cell as it is supposed to do. I am not sure what is wrong.

Webapp1 - accessed by user (showing only one relevant function. There is more not relevant code which I excluded to show a simple example):

EDITED CODE:

```
function ServerSideFunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kLZ3CHPkODHRc_judkUSJ3ocWVPh6nIIjJS7TLLejIg');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Database');

  var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script....../macros/s/.....s/exec");

}
```

Webapp2: (the one published in the URL above and run as me)

```
function test() {
  
  var i = 408 //I would like to pass this as parameter eventually from webapp1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kLZ3CHPkODHRc_judkUSJ3ocWVPh6nIIjJS7TLLejIg');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var str = "OK";
  sh.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(str);
   
}

function doGet() {
  
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('list');
  return output;
  
}
```

Few more notes:

- The two apps are in two different projects in Google Apps Script.
- App2 run OK if executed independently
- When running App1, I noticed App2 is not executed from my executions logs in Google Apps Script.
- I added try-catch code to see if there is an error when executing. It does not look like there is an error.
- The reponse has ~70000 characters. I am wondering if that is normal.

Comment: A web app requires a doGet or a doPost. And there can be only one web app in a project.

Comment: The Web App that the user uses, should make an external request to a totally different Web App in a different Apps Script file.  Is that how you have it set up?

Comment: Yes, they are in two different projects. However the second app does not have the doGet(). I just tried to add a dummy doGet in the second webapp, but still not working..

Comment: I checked the execution of my scripts and the second webapp does not get triggered. However when I run it independently (2nd app only) it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition:

> if(vA[i][3]+" REQ ID: "+vA[i][0] == value) {

will never be true as anything + "REQ ID: " will never be equal to "TEST"(`value`). Thus the `urlfetch` is never executed.

Comment: I simplified the code when pasting it here, "value" comes as a parameter from the HTML code. It works fine, the condition is met, I tested it. I edited the above to make it even more simple.

Comment: @Filippo What is the `response` and where is `doGet` in web-app2?

Comment: I added the code with the get part. When I copy and paste the URL for webapp2 into the browser, it works. The "response" is 70k+characters with JS code I did not write and I do not understand. I guess it is not normal and that is the issue.

Comment: @Filippo What's web-app2's "access" set as?

Comment: execute as me, anyone has access. Do you think there are some security settings in my company which probably prevent the correct execution of the urlfetch?

Comment: Access should be "anyone, even anonymous". Contact your admin to enable anonymous access @Filippo

Comment: ok, I think that is the issue then. There is a restriction and access is granted only within the company domain. Not sure if they will allow me to change that setting.

Comment: @Filippo If they don't, Try sending authorization headers. Search similar questions